# Ansible - Set environment path as inventory variable

Tags: path, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Osmc media player needs a specific path for playbooks
https://github.com/osmc/osmc/issues/319

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/sbin:/usr/sbin"
```

I was wondering whether I can set this as an environmental variable in the inventory for those machines, rather than have it in every playbook or create separate playbooks.

In common usage - is that path likely to cause problems for general *nix machines if it is implemented on non-osmc installations?

If you can't set this an an inventory variable:
Is that just because it's no implemented/ useful to most?
Or because the inventory has no relation to path - e.g. it's not invoked at that point?

Or is a better way for all of this to have it as a machine specific variable/ task in a role?
How would that look please?

New to ansible and still trying to get my head round some of the concepts.

Comment: The *environment* keyword can be used only at task or playbook level. Why do you have to use different playbooks? Just default variables for your functionality. Remember you are working around an issue.

Comment: Thanks imjoseaangel. Good to know about the environment and if that's the answer feel free to right it as that and I'll accept it.

"Just default variables for your functionality." Could you explain a little further please? Set variables based on a role? Or apply that path to all machines because it will usually be ok?

Apologies if I'm being stupid, learning more every day on this but not quite there yet. Keep walking into old documentation/ tutorials where it's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, the `environment` keyword can be used only at task or playbook level.

You will be able to use an standard playbook just adding the following:

```
---
- name: Environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Setup
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - "!all"
```

or

```
---
- name: Environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: True
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
```

If you debug the variable:

```
---
- name: Environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Setup
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - "!all"

  - name: Debug
    debug:
      var: ansible_env.PATH
```

You will get something like:

```
TASK [Setup] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_env.PATH": "/Users/imjoseangel/source/venv/ansible/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
}
```

And what if you want to pass that variable to another play with different inventory?

Just do `hostvars.localhost.ansible_env.PATH`

```
- name: Environment2
  hosts: windows
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False


  tasks:

  - name: Debug
    debug:
      var: hostvars.localhost.ansible_env.PATH
```

So the

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/sbin:/usr/sbin"
```

Will be valid only with gather_facts or setup module under the defined inventory but you don't need to split playbooks.