# Ansible: How to add Linux modul command path (opkg not in path)

Tags: linux, ansible

My Linux box (busybox) using read-only filesystems mostly. I have option to install my programs different path like `PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin`. The package manager also sitting in this folder (exec. file name: `/opt/bin/opkg`) .
When I want to use Ansible opkg module I got the following error:

```
"Failed to find required executable opkg in paths: /bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Question: How can I say to my Ansible to look for opkg package in different path?

Any ideas are welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: Is `/opt/bin/opkg` a directory?

Comment: No, it is the executable file with full path. I wrote by mistake in my description.

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful link:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html
- [Ansible - Set environment path as inventory variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060350/ansible-set-environment-path-as-inventory-variable)

And here is my example:

```
---
- hosts: CBOX-0001
  gather_facts: True
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
  environment:
    PATH: "/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"  

  collections:
    - community.general
  tasks:
    - name: "install opkg packages"
      opkg:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - screen
        - mc
        - rclone
```